# jolt if else and splitting array into two arrays

Tags: json, jolt

i am trying to write a jolt spec to split this array into two diffrent arrays. one will contain codes starting from "CA" and other will contain "C0"

Input :

```json
{
  "smartCode-ids": "CA_2629,CA_2621,CA_1691,C0_2628,C0_2621,C0_1691"
}
```

jolt spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "smartCode-ids": "=split(',',@(1,smartCode-ids))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "smartCode-ids": {
          "CA*": {
            "@(2,smartCode-ids)": "CA[]"
          }
        },
        "C0*": {
          "@(2,smartCode-ids)": "C0[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

expected output :

```json
{
  "CA":["CA_2629","CA_2621","CA_1691"],
  "C0":["C0_2628","C0_2621","C0_1691"]
}
```

I am getting null

Answer (score 0):

You might change the second transformation like in the following one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "smartCode-ids": "=split(',',@(1,smartCode-ids))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": { // indexes of the array
          "*_*": { // separate the values by underscores
            "$": "&(1,1)" // grab the 1st replacement of
                          // asterisks after going 1 level up the tree
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: thanks for the spec.its giving the output. but i want to further perform operations on "CA" and "C0". i want to perform count operation on both of them and return true if they have more than one code in them. and return false otherwise. with the given solution i wont be able to perform further operations on them and give the final result that is true or false

Comment: Can you please edit the question along with such details and the desired output @RajGandhal